Controller for eBike AVENTON PACE 250
I am looking to change the controller of this eBike in order to resolve error 10and 30.
I checked all the cables and the second suspect would be the controller, I ordered one on ali focusing on its dimensions and rating.
After receiving it, I realized that the connectors that come from the screen + brake are not compatible. Those of the old one have 6 pins while those of the new one have 8 pins.
I'll try to attach some photos:
The old controller

New controller 
Do you have any idea on this subject?
Thanks in advance

Just to start, you probably can't do much without the pin-outs.  An electronics forum might be a better place to ask than here, really, since this is only tangentially related to bicycles.

What do these errors usually signify?

@DavidW This absolutely relates to a bicycle and these questions will become more common as we move from the jolly present and into the bright (or not so bright) electric future.

You could buy a compatible display and brake levers if everything else is plug'n'pray

@Noise  It's tangentially bicycle related.  It's like asking about making your own DOT fluid for brakes; yes bicycles are eventually involved, but it's not about bikes.  And mostly it's basically impossible to answer without knowing the pinouts of the two controllers, having a spare matching connector and the tools to properly assemble it, none of which are cycling tasks.  Some people here could make a guess, but if the question were asked instead on an electronics forum, most potential answers would have actual expertise.

@DavidW You certainly could ask the question on an electronics forum. Similarly, a lot of questions that fit here, or maybe don't fit here, could be asked on an engineering or even industrial history forum. The problem is that if you actually do that, the result is almost guaranteed to be a bunch of frame challenges and discursion from people that know those subjects but don't understand all the many periphery details about bikes that go into getting to a cogent, practical answer. OP's question is absolutely about bicycles and how to fix them.

Thank you all for answering. @DavidW, apologies if you feel it only tangentially related to bicycles, It's an ebike part and my hope is to find some help

I can try to help you here. I don't know what you think the errors shown mean (perhaps you should have added the message meaning and why it led you to think the controller is at fault): I'm not going to look them up for you on this occasion.
The Pace 250 is a Vietnamese-assembled bike from a company based in the US that has been deliberately limited to 250 watts & 15mph, suitable for the UK and EU market, for the distributor, Brick Lane Bikes. As far as I am aware, the US versions of this bike have a 350W nominal output and are limited to 20mph. Newer versions have a Bafang motor but all the connections are the same as the older version with the heavier motor from a different manufacturer.
My first port of call would not have been Alibaba for a replacement controller: you should have gone to BLB: they have some stock of spare parts and the direct link to the manufacturer.
The biggest problem when buying the chinese controllers is that you don't know what system they are designed to support. If you have the motor and battery connections OK on your 3rd party controller, you could replace your display/contoller and brake levers to match the connections on your new controller, if you can find the matching parts. If you open the casing of both controllers, you may be able to establish where wires should be soldered to get the effect you want: usually the circuit boards are labelled. However, if you are confident enough to do that, you may also be competent enough to diagnose the faulty components on the existing controller board and solder in a replacement.
Ultimately it is my opinion that you have made a mistake buying the 3rd party controller and you should either get a replacement from the distributor or manufacturer that is correct for your application, or try again now you know what connectors you need, to find another controller that you can compare photos of with your original unit.
The biggest problem with many of these bikes is the incompatibility between various 3rd party components that make up the system. There are far more variables trying to replace parts from these systems if they are not supported any longer by the bicycle manufacturer (specifically thinking of some of the early brands that are now defunct). Keeping some of these bikes on the road is proving to be quite challenging.
You are in a good position because the bike is still currently available and the manufacturer and distributor are good to deal with. Should that ever change, your situation would involve more work on your part to reach a solution.

Thanks @Noise for taking time to answer. What do you mean by BLB, I google it and find "Brick Lane Bikes" but they sell only classical bike parts

Yes, the distributor is Brick Lane Bikes (BLB BIG MAMA) and you should be able to call or email. The Pace is discontinued now so not advertised on the consumer site. @tazer
